# Null Data Returning From DB - C# MVC ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I have a simple table with three columns `ID` `Name` `IsSelected`.  The latter is a `nullable` `bit`, so naturally my class: `city.cs` for each row of this table has generated a `nullable` `bool` for this property.  However, when I debug the code, `IsSelected` is returning `null` for each row, when indeed there are values ranging from `0` to `1`as I manually typed them into the table.

If I run this line of code:

```
var test = cities.ToList();
if(test[0].IsSelected.HasValue)
{
   return "yes";
}
```

The `if` statement fails.  I could generate another table and uncheck `allow nulls` in `ssms`, but first, I would like to know why I'm getting this problem.

Here is the table if this helps:

[image: City Table]

Comment: Have all your other properties (ID, Name) their expected values?

Comment: Yes, (ID and Name) are working as expected.  ID is an `int` and Name is a `nvarchar(50)`.

Comment: Strange, your code looks fine. I'm afraid we'll need a [mcve] for that one.

Answer (score 0):

so they are nullable columns you need to code it like this:

```
var test = cities.ToList();
if(test[0]!=null && test[0].Value.IsSelected)
{
   return "yes";
}
```

or

```
var test = cities.ToList();
if(test[0].HasValue && test[0].Value.IsSelected)
{
   return "yes";
}
```

Comment: see also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types

Comment: Hi - I understand what you say, but it still doesn't answer the fact that I am getting null data from that column, when there is data there (see table image above)